# Finding if registry key exists HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{3BDAAC43-E734-11D5-93AF-00105A990292}

Tags: c#, registry

I have a bool function that checks for the existence of a registry key:

```
  private bool KeyExists(RegistryKey RootKey, string subKeyName)
    {
        RegistryKey ret = RootKey.OpenSubKey(subKeyName);
        if (ret == null)  {return false;}
        else { return true; }
    }
```

In my code,

```
if (!KeyExists(Registry.ClassesRoot, (@"\CLSID\{3BDAAC43-E734-11D5-93AF-00105A990292}")))
    {
            //create the subkey;
    }
```

The key, copied from regedit is

```
HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{3BDAAC43-E734-11D5-93AF-00105A990292}
```

Even though the key exists, the function, KeyExists() always returns false.

If I replace the call to KeyExists() thusly:

```
            if (!KeyExists(Registry.LocalMachine, (@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\")))
```

The function returns true.

Unlike all the examples I've found here and elsewhere, I'm checking for a CLSID and I'm pretty sure I'm not passing the parameter correctly.

Comment: The following may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72654434/10024425 - it's VB.NET, but should be easy to convert.

Comment: It's good that you have a version that works and a version that doesn't. That way, you can compare them to look for any differences. For example, the one that doesn't work begins with an extra ``\``.

Comment: That sounds like a different question.