# How to edit object array adding new data to set in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
    List<ChartView> data = new List<ChartView>();
    var chartData = new object[data.length+1];
    chartData[0] = new object[]
                   {
                       "Chart",
                       "Standard",
                       "BL"
                   };
    int j = 0;
    foreach (var i in data)
    {
         j++;
         chartData[j] = new object[] 
                        { 
                            i.particulars,
                            i.originalDocuments,
                            i.filingOfEntries,
                            i.assessmentOfDuties, 
                            i.paymentOfDuties, 
                            i.releasing, 
                            i.gatePass, 
                            i.delivery 
                        };

    }
```

How can i add new data in object without deleting the old data. In the above code charttData[0] have 3 value **Chart,Standard,BL**. I need to add new string to the set of object. It should become **Chart,Standard,BL,Sample**.

I am working on dynamic line chart like this. The number of lines must be dynamic it could be 1,2 or morethan 10.
[image]

Please note that this question is not about [Add new item in existing array in c#.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249452/add-new-item-in-existing-array-in-c-net) (which was earlier suggested as duplicate).

Comment: You can only create new array with new size then copy source array with Array.Copy.

Comment: @Alexei Levenkov this is not a duplicate post. please check my post carefully and compare it to the link you've given.

Comment: Use `List<string>`. Example: `var chartData = new List<string> { "Chart", "Standard", "BL" };` and then add new item as `chartData.Add("sample");`

Comment: I read your post several times, but I don't get how it is different from adding an item to array. The only interpretation of "add new string to the set of object" I can come up with is "add a new `Sample` string to end of array stored in `charttData[0] `". Quite possibly it is not what you looking for, but your intention is not clear from your post.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov it's like array inside an array. You flag it as a duplicate but it is not clear to you.

Comment: @Reynan I said that based on reading of *your post* (not guessing your goals) I believe it is duplicate, I suspect you have some other intention but it is not present in the post currently (or I'm not able to see it). Hopefully people who able to read your post differently will add comments while voting to reopen (so I can learn too).

Comment: I've re-opened question. When asnwering make sure to check suggestions covered in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249452/add-new-item-in-existing-array-in-c-net as none of them helped OP.

Answer (score 0):

I try my best to understand your question, base on my understanding what your goal is to add new type of graph in your "`object[]` *bla bla bla...*" and each type of graph can use the content of data?

If my understanding is correct, I suggest to use Dictionary instead of confusing object array, by using Dictionary you can easily add new type of graph just like my example below:

```
List < ChartView > data = new List < ChartView > ();

Dictionary < string, List < ChartView >> graphType = new Dictionary < string, List < ChartView >> () {
    {
        "Chart", data
    }, {
        "Standard", data
    }, {
        "BL", data
    }
}; // First you only have 3 kind of graphs.

grapType.Add("Sample", data); // this will allow you to add another graph named sample.
```

**Note:** This is just example how to use dictionary.