# Unique Randomiser method - C#

Tags: c#, arrays, loops, random, methods

Basically i'm creating a method that randomises a number then either returns 0 or the random value. (Depending upon if an array already has that value stored in it). There's currently 2 problems. Not all paths return a value. And the last part of my loop (i++) is unreachable. Any help would be great.
Also heres the array that i created for the randomiser:

```
int[] arr = new int[4];
```

Heres the method:

```
public int UniqueRandomiser()        
{
    Random rnd = new Random();

       int j = rnd.Next(1, 4);
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            if (rand1[i] == j)
            {
                return 0;
            }
            else
            {
                return j;
            }

        }   
}
```

Comment: Move the `return j;` to after the `for` loop.

Comment: Are you *sure* you're not actually looking for something like: `int[] shuffled = Enumerable.Range(1, 4).OrderBy(x => rnd.Next()).ToArray();`?

Comment: Because it *looks* like you just want the numbers `1` to `4` in random order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `.Contains` on the array to check if the number exists:

```
return randomArray.Contains(randomNumber) ? 0 : randomNumber;
```

EDIT: If we require to check only the first 4 numbers:

```
return randomArray.Take(4).Contains(randomNumber) ? 0 : randomNumber;
```

Comment: It may occure that `randomArray` has *more* than `4` items (say, `100`) but we should check *first* `4` of them only.

Comment: Well, it that case just __take__ the first 4 items: `randomArray.Take(4).Contains(randomNumber)`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I'm assuming he wants to check the entire array  "Depending upon if an array already has that value stored in it". Not sure where checking only the first 4 values comes from.

Comment: @Antony - because the loop is `for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)`. So technically it's only checking the first four items. But since the array is declared as `new int[4]`, that might as well be "the whole" array. But if so, the loop should be declared as `for (int i = 0; i < rand1.Length; i++)` to make it obvious. We don't really know what the magic number `4` is supposed to mean. We can only guess.

Comment: I need to then store the random number in the array if it isn't already there.

Comment: @WowFactsWrong why not use a`List` - will be easier to add the numbers. For adding to an array you will have to resize it: [add new item in existing array in c net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249452/add-new-item-in-existing-array-in-c-net)

Comment: @Antony Im new to C# and lists were removed from a syllabus/specification for the year.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using *Linq* and make the code being *readable*:

```
// Do not recreate Random (or you're going to have badly skewed values); 
// the simplest, but not thread safe
private static Random rnd = new Random();

public int UniqueRandomiser() {
  //TODO: what does 4 stand for? Get rid of magic numbers...
  int v = rnd.Next(1, 4);

  //TODO: another magic number 4; is it connected with the previous one?
  // if any of first 4 items of rand1 is equal to v return 0
  return rand1.Take(4).Any(item => item == v) ? 0 : v;  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The "unreachable" for the `i++` is because the first time through the loop, it `return`s on every code path - so the `i++` will indeed never be reached. The other error is because there *is* a hypothetical (but actually impossible) code path that doesn't return a value - if the loop ran to completion (it can't) without returning a value, then there is no return value from the method.

I expect you meant:

```
public int UniqueRandomiser()        
{
    Random rnd = new Random();

    int j = rnd.Next(1, 4);
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        if (rand1[i] == j)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }   
    return j;
}
```

However.. this still looks like a very bad way to do ... whatever it is you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you need.

```
public int UniqueRandomiser()        
{
    Random rnd = new Random();

    int j = rnd.Next(1, 4);

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        if (rand1[i] == j)
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return j;
}
```

It doesn't really make sense though. If the number returned must be unique, it's not a truly random number.

Comment: Im using the generator to call upon forms and i dont want the same form being called more that once - we haven't yet been taught how to do lists so we have to use an array.