# add an element at a certain position of a char array?

Tags: c#, arrays

Want to add an element at a certain position of a char array. Tried to use Concat but showed error, maybe some reference was missing. Also tried to find similar question but found none.

Please see following code and to add element at the end of the array and also at any index of that array.

```
                         char[] c = { 'a','b','c','d' };

                         //add elements.

                         // c.Concat//c.add//[c.Length] = 'e';
```

Thanks.

Comment: `c = c.Take(2).Concat(new char[] { 'e' }).Concat(c.Skip(2)).ToArray();` (assuming you want to insert at index 2 which is the third position in the array).

Comment: it looks a lot operations, so will it be better if I go with "List" approach?

Comment: Yes. Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249452/add-new-item-in-existing-array-in-c-net

Comment: If my code above doesn't work, add `using System.Linq;` to the top of the file.

Comment: Yes, better is to use `List`, take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 4):

The array size is static, so you can't add elements to it. However, if you really, really want to insert an element into it, you can [resize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348051(v=vs.110).aspx) the array, then shift the elements from the desired position one place to the right, and then set the new element. For example you can have this function:

```
public static void InsertInArray(ref char[] array, char element, int pos)
{
    // Check that index is inside the bounds
    if (pos < 0 || pos > array.Length)
    {
        throw new IndexOutOfRangeException();
    }

    // Resize the array
    Array.Resize(ref array, array.Length + 1);

    // Shift elements one place to the right, to make room to new element
    for (int i = array.Length - 1; i > pos; i--)
    {
        array[i] = array[i-1];
    }

    // Set new element
    array[pos] = element;
}
```

Then, for example:

```
public static void Main()
{       
    var myChars = new char[] { 'b', 'c', 'e' };

    // Insert in position 0
    InsertInArray(ref myChars, 'a', 0);

    // Print array: a,b,c,e
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", myChars));

    // Insert in position 3
    InsertInArray(ref myChars, 'd', 3);

    // Print array: a,b,c,d,e
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", myChars));

    // Insert in position 5
    InsertInArray(ref myChars, 'f', 5);

    // Print array: a,b,c,d,e,f
    Console.WriteLine(string.Join(",", myChars));
}
```

Full example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/pLhTzP

Comment: Thanks a lot for a broad explanation to this answer. Will you confirm if going with "List" approach will be better for performance?

Comment: As a general rule, `List` is better for these kinds of scenarios @bulliedMonster.

Comment: @mjwills can you please mention how to convert a string to a List?

Comment: To convert an array to a list use `ToList` @bulliedMonster. Also consider using a `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
var myList = new char[] { 'a','b','d','e' }.ToList();
myList.Insert(2, 'c');
// View the results: "a,b,c,d,e"
```

Comment: It is for Javascript. It is under [JavaScript Base Type Extensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-3.5/bb397506(v%3dvs.90)) docs.

Comment: @GuillermoGutiérrez: I thought question has a c# tag!!

Comment: The question is about `C#`, your answer is for JavaScript =]

Comment: @Hooman I mean that `Array.insert` is a Javascript function, according to the MS documentation you are referring to.

Comment: Its for c#. It would be great to see the ans for c#. And in c# there's no Array reference, so no Array.insert available.

Comment: @GuillermoGutiérrez: oops, that's my bad. I will update my answer. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1):

Array has this disadvantage, that it has fixed size and in order to add elements you have to resize it, which is inconvinient.

I would suggest you to use some collection, like `List` to perform such operations.

For example:

```
List<char> chars = new List<char>{ 'a','b','c','d' };
// add character at the end
chars.Add('e');
```

You can read more [**here**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 0):

use somthing like this:

```
var list = c.ToList();
list.Insert(int index, char item)
```