# How do I add just one element to an array when I call a method c#

Tags: c#, arrays

Im trying to call a method with a switch case menu that lets the user add just 1 element to the array each time the method is called, but I either end up having to fill the entire array at once or it just resets everytime i call it.

So my question is, how do I only add one element each time i call the array but still have the array remember previous entries?

EDIT: I have to use an array for this.

```
    public void add_passenger()
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter age of passenger");
            Passenger[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        }

    }
```

Comment: Do you want to add the item to the next available array location (i.e. calling add_passenger the first time updates `[0]`, the second time `[1]`, the third `[2]`, etc.)?

Comment: Yes,thats exactly right.

Comment: Your array is dynamically sized (it grows as the user wishes it to). Use a List instead. Also that `For` loop is doing 100% nothing. Just get rid of it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add new item in existing array in c#.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249452/add-new-item-in-existing-array-in-c-net)

Comment: Passenger if its class need definition and add through list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way would to be make your `i` variable global across the class:

```
private int arrayNum = 0;  // this is i
```

Then:

```
public void add_passenger()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter age of passenger");
    Passenger[arrayNum] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    arrayNum++;
}
```

## Note: you need to check that `i < Passenger.Length` before calling `add_passenger()`

Comment: You forgot to replace i with arrayNum ;)

Comment: Good catch, @Yosh. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to dynamically size the collection its much easier to use a List instead of array. if it needs to be an array, and you're not too worried about performance you can always do something like

```
public void Add_passenger()
{
       var PassengerList=new List<int>(Passenger);
       Console.WriteLine("Enter age of passenger");
       PassengerList.Add(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
       Passenger=PassengerList.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: I am creating a list using the array in the constructor (thus populating the list with all the fields of the array), than create new array from that list (with one added field), and replacing the array reference with the new array (so by the end it is again and array containging an extra element