# Append array values to dictionary if key exists

Tags: c#, arrays, dictionary

I am trying to create a `dictionary<string,DocValueModelClass>` where `DocValueModelClass` is a model class having few array components.

So when a key exists in dictionary, I would like to append the array value to dictionary where the key exists. When I tried to add the value it appends the whole as a class overwriting all the data in the model class `DocValueModelClass` ending with just value in the array in dictionary.

```
if (data.Length == 5)
{
    docValueModelClass.type = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["type"];
    docValueModelClass.destinationValue = new string[] { data[0] };
    docValueModelClass.sourceKey = new string[] { data[1] };
    docValueModelClass._name = data[2];
    docValueModelClass.description = data[3];
    docValueModelClass.title = data[2];

    if (jsonDictionary.ContainsKey(data[4]))
    {
        jsonDictionary[data[4]] = docValueModelClass;
    }
    else
    {
        jsonDictionary.Add(data[4], docValueModelClass);
    }
}
```

I wanted to just append the array values to `docValueModelClass.destinationValue` and `docValueModelClass.sourceKey` if the key exists and not overwrite. Please suggest on how I can achieve this. Tried to check online and didn't find anything on how I can fix this.

Comment: Do you know how to "add elements" to the array - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249452/add-new-item-in-existing-array-in-c-net/249486? That's what you need - just get the already stored value (`jsonDictionary[data[4]]`) and modify its `destinationValue` and `sourceKey`.

Comment: @EugenePodskal: Thanks a lot. In-spite of having it as array, I changed the member to list and added the value. Now it seems to append the value to the list in the dictionary.

Comment: I recommend looking into the [`GroupBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby) or [`ToLookup`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.tolookup) methods

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION:**

You should modify only the property of the dictionary object if it exists, not the entire object by creating a new object.

```
if (jsonDictionary.ContainsKey (data[4])) {
  // Updates only the property of existing object
  jsonDictionary[data[4]].destinationValue = new string[] { data[0] };
  jsonDictionary[data[4]].sourceKey = new string[] { data[1] };
} else {
  docValueModelClass = new DocValueModelClass ();
  docValueModelClass.type = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["type"];
  docValueModelClass.destinationValue = new string[] { data[0] };
  docValueModelClass.sourceKey = new string[] { data[1] };
  docValueModelClass._name = data[2];
  docValueModelClass.description = data[3];
  docValueModelClass.title = data[2];
  // Adds the new object
  jsonDictionary.Add (data[4], docValueModelClass);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work as the value still keeps overwriting the destinationValue and sourceKey. As suggested by Eugene above, I tried to mark the value as list inspite of array as below:                                                docValueModelClass.destinationValue = new List<string> { data[0] };
                                        docValueModelClass.sourceKey = new List<string> { data[1] }; if (jsonDictionary.ContainsKey(data[4]))
 {
    jsonDictionary[data[4]].destinationValue.Add(data[0]);
    jsonDictionary[data[4]].sourceKey.Add(data[1]);
}

Comment: Check this code: https://dotnetfiddle.net/byIVRP and try to reproduce the issue here.

Comment: Thanks @Naveen, I will check on the same.